# How to automatically create a page?

Tags: php, javascript, html

Here is my website : http://searchr.us/web-search.phtml

So now,once anyone searches in that page it comes like this :

```
http://searchr.us/web-search.phtml?search=SEARCHED+TEXT
```

So now what i want to do is that when a person searches anything for that matter.A page with its title called

```
http://searchr.us/web-search.phtml?search=SEARCHED+TEXT.html
```

Or something like that which has the keywords in the title and the content he searched in the body.

Hope you understood the question.

Thanking You,
5416339

Comment: I think you'll need mod_rewrite (if it's apache and you have chance to use it).

Comment: Do you mean that you want the results of the search statically stored in an HTML file and that file retrieved any time the same search is made?

Comment: "     
flag
    
What have you tried so far ... and where are you having trouble? "

Comment: @David..yah kind of...But i just want to save the file for the time being

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The question mark is not valid in a URL path; it is used to separate the path from the query string. You will need to detect the presence of a previous search and serve that content up yourself. Putting the search results in a file named after the search terms in a separate directory is a good idea though. See `fopen()`, `fwrite()`, `fclose()`, and `readfile()`.

Comment: Thanks will look at this.Any better suggestion ?

Comment: The file I/O operations are probably the easy part.  Creating the static file with fully-rendered output will be a little more complex, though not a terribly big deal with a decent template system.  Probably just keep a standard search result template with a place to insert the content, open it, do a string place to insert the content, save as a new file.

Comment: And do this opening and creating a file each time they search will make my search results a little slow ? Because this has to happen simultaneously right ?

Comment: Unless the search is incredibly fast (probably on the order of tens of milliseconds or less), the file output will be only a very tiny fraction of the delay before the page comes up.

Comment: Ok,Then i think i run the Copying function at the footer.Why do you think ?

Comment: I would do it after you've sent everything to the client and flushed it.

Comment: Ok,Thank you for your support.See you around and ave a nice day !!

Comment: Beware of including files by referencing them directly by name in the URL.  That could lead to hackers obtaining sensible files from your server.  Name the files with a transformation of the string (like an MD5, for instance), and find them later by applying the same transformation again to the search string.

Comment: It's more reliable to URL-encode the search phrase, since hashes do collide on occasion.